# Does Robe of Eyes penetrate Darkness?

Tags: spells, magic-items, adnd-2e, vision-and-light

In AD&D 2e, the Robe of Eyes has this description:

> This valuable garment appears to be a normal robe until it is put on. Its wearer is able to "see'' in all directions at the same moment due to scores of magical "eyes'' which adorn the robe. The wearer also gains infravision to a range of 120 feet, and the power to see displaced or out-of-phase objects and creatures in their actual positions. The robe of eyes sees all forms of invisible things within a 240-foot normal vision range (or 120 feet if infravision is being used).
>
> *Invisibility*, *dust of disappearance*, *robes of blending*, and *improved invisibility* are not proof against observation, but astral or ethereal things cannot be seen by means of this robe. Solid objects obstruct even the robe's powers of observation. Illusions and secret doors also can't be seen, but creatures camouflaged or hidden in shadows are easily detected, so ambush or surprise of a character wearing a robe of eyes is impossible.

Would a robe of eyes be able to see into an area affected by a *Darkness 15′ radius* spell? Note that that spell is *alteration* magic, not *illusion*, but also states that infravision does not penetrate.

Comment: Just for giggles ... does the bit about `solid objects obstruct the robe's powers` mean that the wearer wouldn't be able to *see through a glass window* via the robe?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### No, it wouldn't.

The fact that the description makes explicit mention of "normal vision" and "infravision" it is clear that some form of light must be coming from an object for it to be seen by the "eyes". Darkness spell "causes total, impenetrable darkness" (pg 140 of the original PHB), hence a lack of any light; and even "infravision is useless" within its area of effect. So the robe would not be of help against darkness.

We can also compare the description of what the robe can do with the description of the "Detect Invisibility" spell. In "Detect Invisibility" it is clearly stated that the wizard will be able to see invisible objects or beings, and in addition those that are "astral, ethereal, or out of phase", and those that are "hidden or concealed" (page 141 of the original PHB). So we could argue that the descriptions of various magical items and spells are quite complete in the core rulebooks.